# firestore rules and batch writes to a same array

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to do batch writes to a same array multiple time.

```
writeBatch.updateData(ref, {
    'testField':FieldValue.arrayUnion('firstReference')
  });
writeBatch.updateData(ref, {
    'testField':FieldValue.arrayUnion('secondReference')
  });
writeBatch.updateData(ref, {
    'testField':FieldValue.arrayUnion('thirdReference')
  });
```

But seems `request.resource.data.testField.size()` is `3` and `resource.data.testField.size()` is `0` rule only call one time in that path , I though firestore would call every write.because i want to using `exists` to detect every reference is correct or not.Anyone have suggestion to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with a transaction or batch write, the entire set of changes appears as a single change in terms of enforcing security rules, because the entire batch of changes on a single document must be allowed or denied all at once.

If you require that the batch of updates be any size, what you're trying to do isn't possible because security rules doesn't have any iteration, nor does it have any way to apply some function to each item of a list.  If you can assume the length of the list, you could index directly into each item to do something with each item.

Your last resort might be to batch write into different document, so that they all get checked individually by rules that match those documents, then use Cloud Functions to copy those changes into place after they occur.  But in this case, those changes would not be applied atomically.

If you would like to see more flexibility in security rules to handle lists of data, you should [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).